# I want to draw a line in canvas dont know which event i should use?

Tags: html, canvas

I want to draw a line in canvas I want to click on a particular area and then drag to ending area to draw line between starting and ending cordinates I am not sure which event i should be using. I will first click on a particular location in canvas and then drag my mouse to the ending location. To which i need the line to be drawn. Can anybody please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035764/draw-a-line-with-two-mouse-clicks-on-html5-canvas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am sure you can figure it out having a look here: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-drag-and-drop.html