# Draw a line with two mouse clicks in canvas using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, click, draw

I have already seen this question

> [Draw a line with two mouse clicks on HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035764/draw-a-line-with-two-mouse-clicks-on-html5-canvas)

What I want to achieve is practically the same, but using Jquery.

I have currently tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nCFPy/), but I guess I can't use two nested click events.

```
 $(function() {

 var worksheetCanvas = $('#worksheet-canvas');

 var context = worksheetCanvas.get(0).getContext("2d");


context.strokeStyle = "rgb(251, 243, 243)";


 worksheetCanvas.click(function(e) {

    context.beginPath();


    var xCoordFirst = e.pageX;
    var yCoordFirst = e.pageY;

    context.moveTo(xCoordFirst, yCoordFirst);


    worksheetCanvas.click(function(f) {

        var xCoordSecond = f.pageX;
        var yCoordSecond = f.pageY;

        context.lineTo(xCoordSecond , yCoordSecond );
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();

     })

  })


 })​
```

Also when I put some static values in `lineTo()`, I get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9jPKb/), which recognizes the coordinates for the second point, thus drawing the line, even though it is useless if the user doesn't set by themselves the second point.

```
 $(function() {

 var worksheetCanvas = $('#worksheet-canvas');

 var context = worksheetCanvas.get(0).getContext("2d");


context.strokeStyle = "rgb(251, 243, 243)";


worksheetCanvas.click(function(e) {

    context.beginPath();


    var xCoordFirst = e.pageX;
    var yCoordFirst = e.pageY;

    context.moveTo(xCoordFirst, yCoordFirst);


    worksheetCanvas.click(function(f) {

        var xCoordSecond = f.pageX;
        var yCoordSecond = f.pageY;

        context.lineTo(20 , 30);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();

    })

 })


})​
```

Comment: Always put the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var mouse = {
    x: -1,
    y: -1
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var cvs = $("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
    $("canvas").click(function(e){
        if(mouse.x != -1 && mouse.y != -1){
            cvs.beginPath();
            cvs.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
            cvs.lineTo(e.pageX, e.pageY);
            cvs.closePath();
            cvs.stroke();
            mouse.x = -1;
            mouse.y = -1;
        }else{
            mouse.x = e.pageX;
            mouse.y = e.pageY;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It works but I don't understand the -1 values for the variables

Comment: I would have used 0, but you want to be able to click at 0, 0. If I had used 0 it would have messed up the order the code works in.

Comment: Thanks. I really like the conditional statement