# Best way to show .svg file in HTML and draw line over it using mouse

Tags: html, svg

Please advice me the best way to show .svg file in HTML and draw dynamic line over it using mouse

sample svg is here [SVG File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18190667/4.svg)

I have used
`<object id='svgObj' type='image/svg+xml' data='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18190667/4.svg'></object>` 
but not able to get what I want

Answer (score 0):

you can show it like this:

```
<embed src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18190667/4.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nAHze/

Comment: But it's deprecated in HTML4

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
</canvas>
```

Styles:

```
canvas {
    border: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);
    background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18190667/4.svg);
}
```

Refer this link to Draw lines in Canvas

[Draw a line with two mouse clicks on HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035764/draw-a-line-with-two-mouse-clicks-on-html5-canvas)